# Static grass animation - grass looks differently in different frames (it's not animated though)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, particles

I made some grass using Particle System and grouped grass objects (each object is a clump with lots of blades).
I didn't do anything to the grass, the only thing that has any keyframes during my animation is a ball rolling through the grass.
The "emitting" plane has a collision component and so does the ball.

The problem is, in over half of the frames the whole grass field looks the same, but in some frames it looks like a clump or two disappear and different ones are suddenly visible. It's very annoying and I don't understand how this can happen.

I attach two frames, the first one is the "normal one" and the second is the odd one.

Thanks for any suggestions! Cheers.

PS Look at the middle - far right or at the middle part of the attached pictures. This is where the discrepancies are.

[image: Normal frame]

[image: Odd frame]

[image: Particle System settings]

Comment: Did you set the start emit and end emit values to be the same in the particle systems settings? Nice rendering by the way :)

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm sorry but I really can't find the settings you're talking about. Where precisely are they?

Comment: When you click the tab for the particle systems settings (where you created the particle system for the grass), then there is a section called 'Emission' and there are the 'start' and 'end' values

Comment: I don't have those settings, I added a screenshot of this section.

Comment: I thought you used the 'emitter' type and not the 'hair' type xD What are ParticleSystemGreen and ParticleSystemYellow?

Comment: I have two kinds of grass and wanted to control how much green grass I have and how much yellow there is. The settings of those two systems are almost identical.

Comment: Does this still happen in 2.75a? I seem to remember seeing a bug fix regarding something like this recently..

Comment: I'll have to check, I'm using 2.74. Thanks for that info :)